# Login to Admin Dashboard Problem

Tags: admin, login

I can't login to my Admin dashboard even when I had reset my password from phpmyadmin! How can I solve it. It kept showing this link each time I tried to login with new new password:

http://www.gim.org.ng/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gim.org.ng%2Fwp-admin%2Fprofile.php&reauth=1

Comment: Have you activated any non-default themes or plugins recently?

Comment: It looks like you ain't got debugging activated. Please [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) - [blueprint for `wp-config.php`](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197) - and file an [edit] so we can look at your error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so i just say what i would try if i'm in your situation:

1. have you tried "Lost your password?" which will reset your password to your registered email.
2. phpmyadmin user table reset the password but in hashed value.
3. if still can not just deploy a clean wordpress fast enough, and migrate your files again on it, won't be a lot of trouble.

Comment: ok BOBO, I've tried the first and second but didn't work. Resolving to install a new WP instance because we suspected we hacked site.